# Google + throwing Javascript error on IE8 while using back button

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, google-plus, google-plus-one

I get Javascript error due to Google + icon on IE 8 when re-visiting the page using back button. Any ideas / help is greatly appreciated.

**Here is my code:**

```
<div class="googleplus1">
   <g:plusone></g:plusone>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
```

**Here is the error I get:**

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; GTB7.4; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; BRI/2)
Timestamp: Wed, 13 Mar 2013 17:11:30 UTC

Message: m`I0_1363194676562
Line: 2
Char: 17
Code: 0
URI: https://apis.google.com/_/scs/apps-static/_/js/k=oz.gapi.en_US.I5-InDPlzyY.O/m=plusone/am=QQ/rt=j/d=1/rs=AItRSTMyDUrNu14AMpe4s29RHFxVrgAi-w/cb=gapi.loaded_0
```

**Here are the steps to reproduce:**

(1) Click on the link below using Internet Explorer 8; it displays cruise search results. (You can close the sign up pop up). You'll see Goggle + icon in the header.

http://www.cruisesonly.com/results.do?wdos=3&places=ALL&c=ALL&days=ALL&p=ALL&Month=ALL&porttype=E&SType=P&ptype=c&type=c&shoppingZipCode=Zip+Code&SType=A&clp=1&sort=7&IncludeSeniorRates=false&IncludeAlumniRates=false&AlumniCruiseId=false&Search.x=22&Search.y=21

(2) Select any item from the search result. You'll see Google + icon in the header on the next page.

(3) Hit the back button to go back to search result and you'll get a javascript error. Google + icon will not load.

Thanks in advance!
Sid